# Unable to resolve IP adress to my domain name but the other way round works

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, nslookup

I am able to resolve my domain name to IP address but not the other way. i.e., unable to resolve IP address to domain name. When I do a nslookup my IP address is getting resolved to the same IP address instead of domain name

**mydomain.in** is my purchased domain name,
**3.71.149.103** is the IP address of the AWS ubuntu instance
Below are the output of nslookup from my PC on internet.

C:\Users\user1>**nslookup mydomain.in**
Server:  broadband.actcorp.in
Address:  49.205.75.2

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    **mydomain.in**
Address:  **3.71.149.103**

C:\Users\user1>**nslookup 3.71.149.103**
Server:  broadband.actcorp.in
Address:  49.205.75.2

Name:    e**c2-3-7-149-103.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com**
Address:  **3.71.149.103**

Can you please guide me how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I am not much into DNS and stuff, but here, when you try to nslookup , AWS EC2 replies with its DNS host name. Either public DNS hostname or private, based on what IP you have used.

ec2-3-7-149-103.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com is public DNS hostname.

For resolving domain name from IP, you might need to configure PTR records, which are just like A records, but in a reverse way.

Some references for the same if your domain is on Route53:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/route-53-reverse-dns/

Comment: Thanks will go through on it.

Comment: PTR record is already added, when i do nslookup ip address, it is getting resolved to my hostname(ec2-3-7-149-103.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com ) not my domain name.
Any idea where do i need to change this ec2-3-7-149-103.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com to my domian name mydomain.in

Comment: This is resolved after writing to AWS team, they need to make changes.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance